# Regular expression for photo name not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use `preg_match` to have every photo whose filename is `gallery\album\U[digits].jpg` be titled "Untitled".

Here is the code:

```
foreach($photos as $photo){ 
  if (preg_match('.*U[0-9]*\.jpg',$photo)) {
    $title = "Untitled";
  }
  else {
    $title = basename($photo,".jpg");
  }
}
```

Any idea why this isn't matching?  The title of any of these files ends up being "U2" or "U29".

Comment: Well, you aren't matching U*.jpg, you are matching Udigits.jpg

Comment: Yeah, sorry, let me amend that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
if (preg_match('@U[0-9]+.jpg@',$photo)) {
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XymqQJ)**

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you!  Can I ask what the difference is?

Comment: @NaOH - Your expression is correct too just need to add delimiter `@` at start & end of regex to make it work. And replace `[0-9]*` by `[0-9]+`.

Comment: A delimiter could be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.